# Affinity propagation with word vectors, faster implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a list of word vectors (named tuple_vectors - length ~60k), each of which look like the following:

```
  [-2.84658718e+00 -7.74899840e-01 -2.24296474e+00 -8.69364500e-01
  3.90927410e+00 -2.65316987e+00 -9.71897244e-01 -2.40408254e+00
  1.16272974e+00 -2.61649752e+00 -2.87350488e+00 -1.06603658e+00
  2.93374014e+00  1.07194626e+00 -1.86619771e+00  1.88549474e-01
 -1.31901133e+00  3.83382154e+00 -3.46174908e+00 -2.94792175e-01
 -2.77922183e-01 -7.64171720e-01 -2.99903727e+00 -2.41594386e+00 ...
```

I am trying to perform affinity propagation (AP) using the following (this is the top part of AP documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html):

```
print(__doc__)

from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics

# Compute Affinity Propagation
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-50).fit(tuple_vectors)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_

n_clusters_ = len(cluster_centers_indices)
```

The process is taking a very long time. My question is whether there is a faster implementation or whether it is possible to perform AP on vectors of this dimensionality.

Comment: The dimensionality should not matter much, as AP requires a distance matrix anyway. But AP has a slow design. If you want it to be fast, it's no longer AP but some variant.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - is there a fast variant you could suggest?

Comment: I don't know any variants. But you could try other tools, maybe their AP implementation is faster. Often ELKI is much faster, but AP doesn't benefit from indexing (and that's where ELKI shines), so I wouldn't expect a large difference - because of BLAS, sklearn may also be faster. At 60k objects I'd avoid anything that is O(n²) or worse, and I doubt there is an easy way to "variant" or index and make it faster...